# Combinations and Permutations of characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I am trying to come up with elegant code that creates combinations/permutations of characters from a single character:

E.g. from a single character I'd like code to create these permutations (order of the result is not important):

```
'a' ---->  ['a', 'aa', 'A', 'AA', 'aA', 'Aa']
```

The not so elegant solutions I have thus far:

```
# this does it...
from itertools import permutations
char = 'a'
p = [char, char*2, char.upper(), char.upper()*2]
pp = [] # stores the final list of permutations
for j in range(1,3):
    for i in permutations(p,j):
        p2 = ''.join(i)
        if len(p2) < 3:
            pp.append(p2)
print pp
['a', 'aa', 'A', 'AA', 'aA', 'Aa']

#this also works...
char = 'a'
p = ['', char, char*2, char.upper(), char.upper()*2]
pp = [] # stores the final list of permutations
for i in permutations(p,2):
    j = ''.join(i)
    if len(j) < 3:
        pp.append(j)
print list(set(pp))
['a', 'aa', 'aA', 'AA', 'Aa', 'A']

# and finally... so does this:
char = 'a'
p = ['', char, char.upper()]
pp = [] # stores the final list of permutations
for i in permutations(p,2):
    pp.append(''.join(i))
print list(set(pp)) + [char*2, char.upper()*2]
['a', 'A', 'aA', 'Aa', 'aa', 'AA']
```

I'm not great with lambdas, and I suspect that may be where a better solution lies.

So, could you help me find the most elegant/pythonic way to the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with different `repeat` values to get the expected result

```
>>> pop = ['a', 'A']
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [''.join(item) for i in range(len(pop)) for item in product(pop, repeat=i + 1)]
['a', 'A', 'aa', 'aA', 'Aa', 'AA']
```

Comment: Oooh, I like it. Though I would do this to make it less complicated:
pop + [''.join(item) for item in product(pop, repeat=2)]

Comment: @JayMarm The answer I provided is a generic one. You can customize it as per your needs.